# submitting form via python requests/bs

Tags: python, python-3.x, forms, beautifulsoup, request

I have the following form on a webpage:

```
<form method="POST" action="" name=“x”>Saison (click): 
    <input style="border:1px dotted silver;background-color:white" name=“y” value="2011" type="submit">
    <input style="border:1px dotted silver;background-color:white" name=“y” value="2012" type="submit">
    <input style="border:1px dotted silver;background-color:white" name=“y” value="2013" type="submit">
    <input style="border:1px dotted silver;background-color:white" name=“y” value="2014" type="submit">
    <input style="border:1px dotted silver;background-color:white" name=“y” value="2015" type="submit">
    <input style="border:1px dotted silver;background-color:white" name=“y” value="2016" type="submit">
    <input style="border:1px dotted silver;background-color:white" name=“y” value="2017" type="submit">
    <input style="border:1px dotted silver;background-color:white" name=“y” value="2018" type="submit">
</form>
```

I would like to use BeautifulSoup and request to get the webpage that generates when i press one of the submit buttons. How does this work?

Comment: Just know Selenium could help, not sure of bs or request.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: @KeyurPotdar https://www.oejv.com/bundesliga/tabellestandings/
I want to change between the years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Network tab, in the developer tools, you can see that the form data contains only `jama_saison:2013`. So, to pass this data, you've to use this:

```
year = 2013
data = {'jama_saison': year}
r = requests.post('https://www.oejv.com/bundesliga/tabellestandings/', data=data)
```

To test whether we've got the correct response:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('th', class_='bl-name').text)
# Erste Judo-Bundesliga 2013
```

Just change the `year` variable to whichever year you want. Changing it to 2017, gives *Erste Judo-Bundesliga 2017* as the output.